# overlay a img over a div center horizontal & center vertical over the div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Not sure if It can be done only with css... if it can, i would prefer that...

I have an horizontal line (div) and I want to place an image in the center of the line (horizontally) and (vertically).

I tried this with javascript, but it's not working at all ...

HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
#container {
    background-color:#F00;
    height:5px;
    width: 77%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>

<script>
var logo = document.getElementById('logo');
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var margin = (container.clientHeight - logo.clientHeight) / 2;
logo.style.marginTop = margin + "px";
logo.style.marginBottomn = margin + "px";
</script>

<br><br><br>
<div id="container">
<img src="images/logo_footer.jpg" width="229" height="75"  id="logo" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the css, add margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; and for the top and bottom, you gotta use margin-top: amountpx; and measure it.